# Logs tab not showing up in IntelliJ 2017.1EAP

Tags: intellij-idea

This worked fine with previous intelliJ versions. Logs tab is not activated after GlassFish is started. ***Restore Layout*** button does not help.

**UPDATE**

Here is a part of **idea.log** with exceptions(not sure if it's related to the issue):

```
*2017-02-09 15:19:01,969 [3649406]   INFO - notification.NotificationGroup - Notification group JavaEE is already registered 
java.lang.Throwable
    at com.intellij.notification.NotificationGroup.<init>(NotificationGroup.java:65)
    at com.intellij.notification.NotificationGroup.<init>(NotificationGroup.java:50)
    at com.intellij.notification.NotificationGroup.toolWindowGroup(NotificationGroup.java:82)
    at com.intellij.notification.NotificationGroup.toolWindowGroup(NotificationGroup.java:87)
    at com.intellij.javaee.oss.server.JavaeeServerInstanceImpl.createConnectErrorNotification(JavaeeServerInstanceImpl.java:358)
    at com.intellij.javaee.oss.server.JavaeeServerInstanceImpl$ConnectLogger.reportError(JavaeeServerInstanceImpl.java:544)
    at com.intellij.javaee.oss.server.JavaeeServerInstanceImpl.disconnect(JavaeeServerInstanceImpl.java:186)
    at com.intellij.javaee.oss.server.JavaeeServerConnector.shutdown(JavaeeServerConnector.java:115)
    at com.intellij.javaee.run.execution.J2EEProcessHandlerHelper.destroy(J2EEProcessHandlerHelper.java:199)
    at com.intellij.javaee.run.execution.LocalJavaeeServerProcessHandler.destroyProcessImpl(LocalJavaeeServerProcessHandler.java:157)
    at com.intellij.javaee.run.execution.LocalJavaeeServerProcessHandler.detachProcessImpl(LocalJavaeeServerProcessHandler.java:167)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessHandler$2.run(ProcessHandler.java:126)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessHandler$TasksRunner.execute(ProcessHandler.java:260)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessHandler.detachProcess(ProcessHandler.java:121)
    at com.intellij.javaee.run.execution.LocalJavaeeServerProcessHandler.destroyProcess(LocalJavaeeServerProcessHandler.java:78)
    at com.intellij.javaee.run.execution.J2EEProcessHandlerWrapper$4.onProcess(J2EEProcessHandlerWrapper.java:194)
    at com.intellij.javaee.run.execution.J2EEProcessHandlerWrapper$ProcessCall.lambda$new$0(J2EEProcessHandlerWrapper.java:360)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor$2.run(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:212)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

2017-02-09 15:19:14,501 [3661938]   INFO - ij.compiler.impl.CompileDriver - COMPILATION STARTED (BUILD PROCESS) 

2017-02-09 15:19:14,627 [3662064]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [system]: "C:\Program Files\Java\jbsdk8u112b657_windows_x64\jre\bin\java" -Xmx700m -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.endorsed.dirs=\"\"... (many lines)

2017-02-09 15:19:15,084 [3662521]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stdout]: Build process started. Classpath: C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 171.2014.21/lib/jps-launcher.jar;C:/Program Files/Java/jbsdk8u112b657_windows_x64/lib/tools.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 171.2014.21/lib/optimizedFileManager.jar 

2017-02-09 15:19:25,665 [3673102]   INFO - lij.compiler.impl.CompilerUtil -     COMPILATION FINISHED (BUILD PROCESS); Errors: 0; warnings: 0 took 11175 ms: 0 min 11sec 

2017-02-09 15:19:25,666 [3673103]   INFO - CompilerBackwardReferenceIndex - C:\Users\***\.IntelliJIdea2017.1\system\compile-server\***_pom_b5d31051\backward-refs\version (The system cannot find the path specified) 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\***\.IntelliJIdea2017.1\system\compile-server\***_pom_b5d31051\backward-refs\version (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.$$YJP$$open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(FileInputStream.java)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.backwardRefs.CompilerBackwardReferenceIndex.versionDiffers(CompilerBackwardReferenceIndex.java:155)
    at com.intellij.compiler.backwardRefs.CompilerReferenceReader.exists(CompilerReferenceReader.java:109)
    at com.intellij.compiler.backwardRefs.CompilerReferenceReader.create(CompilerReferenceReader.java:116)
    at com.intellij.compiler.backwardRefs.CompilerReferenceServiceImpl.a(CompilerReferenceServiceImpl.java:359)
    at com.intellij.compiler.backwardRefs.CompilerReferenceServiceImpl.access$600(CompilerReferenceServiceImpl.java:70)
    at com.intellij.compiler.backwardRefs.CompilerReferenceServiceImpl$2.b(CompilerReferenceServiceImpl.java:126)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor$2.run(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:212)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2017-02-09 15:19:25,669 [3673106]   INFO - ntellij.analysis.SonarLintTask - Running SonarLint Analysis for 9 files in 2 modules 

2017-02-09 15:19:25,715 [3673152]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [system]: "C:\Program Files\Java\jbsdk8u112b657_windows_x64\jre\bin\java" -Xmx700m -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.endorsed.dirs=\"\".... (many lines)

2017-02-09 15:19:26,196 [3673633]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stdout]: Build process started. Classpath: C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 171.2014.21/lib/jps-launcher.jar;C:/Program Files/Java/jbsdk8u112b657_windows_x64/lib/tools.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 171.2014.21/lib/optimizedFileManager.jar 

2017-02-09 15:19:27,597 [3675034]   INFO - svn.commandLine.CommandRuntime - Detected warning - svn: warning: W155010: The node 'C:\***\Pom\.idea\sonarlint\.sonartmp' was not found.

2017-02-09 15:19:31,779 [3679216]   INFO - ntellij.analysis.SonarLintTask - SonarLint analysis done 
2017-02-09 15:19:58,557 [3705994]   INFO - svn.commandLine.CommandRuntime - Detected warning - svn: warning: W155010: The node 'C:\***\Pom\.idea\sonarlint\.sonartmp' was not found.*
```

Comment: any errors in IntelliJ log?

Comment: The post updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a .bat script (which stops glassfish domain and deletes old logs) set to be executed before launch in GlassFish server configuration, and IntelliJ for some reason does not load recreated (during deploy process) log files. It loads only those existed before starting deploy.

[image]